# Is there a way to count the number of values in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a newbie studying MSSQL and Database.
I am trying to write a SQL query to count values in the column.
Following table is original one.

```
name value
----------
  A    1
  A    1
  A    2
  B    1
  B    2
```

I want to get a table like this.

```
name  one  two
--------------
  A    2    1
  B    1    1
```

A has two 1 and one 2 and B has one 1 and 2. It seems I can accomplish it using COUNT built-in function. I tried but failed. Is there any idea to do it?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if someone later inserts the values `(C, 3)`?

Comment: What if someone inserts 1 million rows with name='A' and values 1 to 1 million?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select name, sum(case when value=1 then 1 else 0 end) as one,
         sum(case when value=2 then 1 else 0 end) as two
from table_name group by name
```